# json javascript: escape double quotes? concat json with other string

Tags: javascript, json

In JS, I have a dictionary that I stringify with json (json2):

```
my_dict = {"1":"hi you'll", "2":"hello"};
as_string = JSON.stringify(my_dict);
```

I need to add this as a value to a form, but the form itself starts out as a string:

```
var my_form = '<form><input value = "'+as_string+'"></form>'
```

my_form is a string because it gets added to the document as DOM (create node, add innerHTML, insert in document)

The issue is that the double quotes get screwed up - there are quotes in my_dict and quotes in my_form. But isn't json supposed to be escaping the double qoutes? Is that not part of what it does? Or do I need to do this? Or is there some other way??

Comment: No, you need to HTML encode it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my_form is a string because it gets added to the document as DOM (create node, add innerHTML, insert in document)

Generating code by smashing together strings is more pain then it is worth. Don't do it. Use standard DOM, not innerHTML. That will take care of escaping for you.

```
 var frm = document.createElement('form');
 var ipt = document.createElement('input');
 ipt.value = as_string;
 frm.appendChild(ipt);
```

> But isn't json supposed to be escaping the double qoutes?

Encoding as JSON will escape the quotes for the JSON format. You are then embedding the JSON in HTML, so you need to escape it for HTML too. (Or, as I recommend above, bypass HTML and go direct to DOM manipulation).

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode the string for HTML, f.ex using RegExp:

```
as_string = JSON.stringify(my_dict).replace(/\"/g,'&quot;');
```

Or use DOM Manipulation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) if you just want to keep it in the DOM:

```
my_dict = {"1":"hi you'll", "2":"hello"};
as_string = escape(JSON.stringify(my_dict));

// as_string : %7B%221%22%3A%22hi%20you%27ll%22%2C%222%22%3A%22hello%22%7D
```

& [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) when you get the value back,

```
as_string = unescape(as_string)

// as_string : {"1":"hi you'll","2":"hello"}
```

Comment: Espace was deprecated in JavaScript 1.5, so you shouldn't use it.