# Post JSON data without ajax or form

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post

I have a json object that I would like to post. I beleive that Im close but the data isnt getting sent correctly.

data is correctly formatted json string and it works correctly with ajax. However, the page needs to be redirected according to the REST api im requesting. Obviously using ajax, this wouldn't happen.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);

$('<form enctype="application/json" action="/projects" method="POST">' + 
  '<input type="hidden" name="json" value="' + data + '">' +
  '</form>').submit();
```

Comment: So you are using jQUery, but you can't use AJAX?  Why this requirement?

Comment: You can redirect via the client

Comment: @MikeBrant is right, use jQuery.Ajax

Comment: I try this code, I don't know why it **does not submit**. maybe browser security stop this..

Comment: POST request is the same POST request no matter how you send it: AJAX, curl or form submit.

Comment: I append it to the body and then **submit** it. It works..

Comment: You may want to check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429744/can-i-post-json-without-using-ajax

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh it does submit. However the data sent is invalid and cant be retrieved as a json object

Comment: @MichaelMichaelidis I saw this, this isnt my use case. Im not using a form.

Comment: @MikeBrant Because I want the page to redirect as instructed by the REST api. In the controller, it will either redirect to the create page or the index page depending on success or failure. Ajax will return the result into the success function without actually redirecting the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to escape your stringified JSON.

```
var data = $(JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);

function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}

$('<form enctype="application/json" action="/projects" method="POST">' + 
  '<input type="hidden" name="json" value="' + escapeHtml(data) + '">' +
  '</form>').submit();
```

Comment: But beware, Firefox 42 does not allow me to set the enctype to `application/json`. It enforces `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which is good because of CSRF concerns imho. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string contains quotes and it breaks the html.

**Edit:** You can also use **escape(string)** if you don't care if it is in readable format in the hidden input. Then you can use **unescape(string)** to get back your json string. That way you can use the same function to pass it over get requests too ;)

```
{name: "test"}
==>  %7B%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D
```

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696884/986160

Answer (score 0):

What about `Curl` you could post you data like so. You will need a ajax call the PHP function :

```
function sendData($json){

    $url = 'wwww.exemple.com';



    //setting the curl parameters.

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Following line is compulsary to add as it is:

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);



    curl_close($ch);



    return $data;





}
```

This function send a json and get the return from API.

Comment: This is PHP. I think OP needs a JS solution.

Comment: If he cannot use PHP then this isn't useful you are right but it's not specified and this may guide him to a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution but I am using javascript. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but id redirect the page. other solution is using [$.Ajax](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax) or [$.post](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.post)

```
var form = $('<form enctype="application/json" action="/projects" method="POST">' + 
  '<input type="hidden" name="json" value="' + data + '">' +
  '</form>');
form.submit();
```

Comment: Using this, just like my original example, the only data in the request is "json:{"